# How to overlay datapoints on stacked column in excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking to turn something like this:

[image: Stacked Column]

Into this:

[image: StackedColumnWithPoints]

Any ideas?

Comment: What are those data points? Can you please clarify what those dots represent? What does your data look like? What have you tried so far? What has/hasn't worked, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting charting challenge.

Overlay the stack with a scatter chart on the secondary axis. Fine tune the x and y values and the min and max of the scatter chart horizontal axis.
[image]

Comment: Lots to dig into here.  As soon as I have a working model of this, I'll update this as answered but this looks very promising, thank you!

Comment: It took some doing, and I i'm not sure I can fully explain how I did it, but I was able to get it done.  Thanks Teylyn!